# Swift Variables Initialization

Tags: ios, swift, variables, initialization

I have a question about variables initialization in swift.

I have two ways to initialize a variable (as "property" of a class in Objective-C).

Which of them is the most correct?

```
class Class {

  var label: UILabel!

  init() { ... label = UILabel() ... }

}
```

or

```
class Class {

  var label = UILabel()

  init() { … }

}
```

Comment: It's not a question of correctness. It's rather a question of requirements and code styling. If the value of `label` is computed, you will use the first variant. If the value is like a constant, you will tend to the second variant (and probably use `let` instead of `var`). But the exception proves the rule. ;)

Comment: @macmoonshine I was afraid that the second one is a kind of a wrong way to do this. Thank you, now I see :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Actually you have 5 ways to initialize properties.

There is no correct way, the way depends on the needs.
Basically declare objects like `UILabel` always – if possible – as constant (`let`).

The 5 ways are:

- Initialization in the declaration line

  ```
  let label = UILabel(frame:...
  ```
- Initialization in the `init` method, you don't have to declare the property as implicit unwrapped optional.

  ```
  let label: UILabel
  init() { ... label = UILabel(frame:...) ... }
  ```

The first two ways are practically identical.

- Initialization in a method like `viewDidLoad`, in this case you have to declare the property as (implicit unwrapped) optional and also as `var`

  ```
  var label: UILabel!

  on viewDidLoad()
   ...
   label = UILabel(frame:...)
  }
  ```
- Initialization using a closure to assign a default (computed) value. The closure is called once when the class is initialized and it is not possible to use other properties of the class in the closure.

  ```
  let label: UILabel = {
     let lbl = UILabel(frame:...)
     lbl.text = "Foo"
     return lbl
  }()
  ```
- Lazy initialization using a closure. The closure is called (once) when the property is accessed the first time and you can use other properties of the class.
  The property must be declared as `var`

  ```
  let labelText = "Bar"

  lazy var label: UILabel = {
     let lbl = UILabel(frame:...)
     lbl.text = "Foo" + self.labelText
     return lbl
  }()
  ```

Comment: `let label: UILabel(frame:...` <- shouldn't it be `=` instead of `:`?

Comment: Thank you for this great answer!) @vadian

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are correct, but sometimes you should use the initialization in `init()` method. For example, here the `target` for barButton will be not set, cause the `self` does not exist yet.

```
class Foo {
    var barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "add", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.someMethod))

    init(){
        //init here
    }
}
```

The correct way for this case is :

```
class Foo {
    var barButton : UIBarButton? 

    init(){
        barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "add", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.someMethod))
    }
}
```

To sum up, both ways are correct, but you have to consider when to use each one.
More information about it on [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var label: UILabel!
```

The above statements means, the variable label may be nil

```
var label = UILabel()
```

But here it will hold a label value. Because the memory is allocated for that variable. So it will not be nil.

Please find more details here

[What's the difference between var label: UILabel! and var label = UILabel( )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734235/whats-the-difference-between-var-label-uilabel-and-var-label-uilabel)