# Initialize member in view struct

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to have a WKWebView with JavaScript handling in SwiftUI. From [Swift Variables Initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40460118/swift-variables-initialization), I am doing the following: (I am using https://github.com/kylehickinson/SwiftUI-WebView to provide a wrapper for `WKWebView` in SwiftUI that also add valuable layout constraints.)

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        WebView(webView: myWebView)
        .onAppear {
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html")!
            myWebView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            myWebView.load(request)
        }
    }

    class JSHandler : NSObject, WKScriptMessageHandler {
        var contentView: ContentView?

        func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
            print("documentReady")
            contentView!.myWebView.evaluateJavaScript("<Long Script to Transfer Data>") { (result, error) in
            }
        }
    }

    let myJSHandler = JSHandler()

    var myWebView: WKWebView = {
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let controller = WKUserContentController()
        controller.add(myJSHandler , name: "documentReady")
        config.userContentController = controller
        return WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
    }()
}
```

But then I learned from [Instance member cannot be used on type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32351343/instance-member-cannot-be-used-on-type) that this doesn't work because the closure doesn't have reference to self. I need the WKWebView to have dedicated config object so I can't just use the other constructor. I need a reference to it to do `evaluateJavaScript`.

How to make this work?

**EDIT 1**: Add the `body` and mention the framework used to wrap WKWebView.

**EDIT 2**: Added code to clarify that I need two way communications from `WKWebView` to native app via `WKScriptMessageHandler` (to get notified when the HTML document is ready) and from native app to `WKWebView` via `evaluateJavaScript` (to transfer data upon the HTML document is ready).

Comment: Wrap `WKWebView` into UIViewRepresentable, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59790493/12299030.

Comment: @Asperi In the struct WebView, you are using `var webview: WKWebView = WKWebView()` but I need to use the constructor with custom configuration. Wouldn't I encounter the same problem then? (I already use https://github.com/kylehickinson/SwiftUI-WebView to wrap WKWebView into a UIViewRepresentable.)

Comment: Here is alternate https://stackoverflow.com/a/60173992/12299030. You can use whichever works for you.

Comment: @Asperi Thanks for the solution. I would like to point out that since the configuration was done inside the wrapper so if I want to make another WKWebView with a different set of JS methods, I would have to make another wrapper! Another issue is that I need a reference to the `WKWebView` in my `ContentView` so that I can call `evaluateJavaScript`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to configure WKWebView in `init`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private var myWebView: WKWebView

    init() {
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let controller = WKUserContentController()
        controller.add(myJSHandler , name: "documentReady")
        config.userContentController = controller
        myWebView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
    }

    var body: some View {
        WebView(webView: myWebView)
        .onAppear {
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html")!
            myWebView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            myWebView.load(request)
        }
    }

    class JSHandler : NSObject, WKScriptMessageHandler {

        func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
            print("documentReady")
            message.webView?.evaluateJavaScript("<Long Script to Transfer Data>") { (result, error) in
            }
        }
    }

    let myJSHandler = JSHandler()

}
```

Comment: I have just came up with a solution by moving `myWebView` inside `JSHandler` but then I don't know what to name `JSHandler` as it not only handles JavaScript callbacks but also serves as a wrapper for the WKWebView. This is much better. Thanks for the tip of using `message.webView?` instead of using a reference to `ContentView` by the way.

Comment: You just cannot use reference to ContentView, because it is not a reference-type, it would be a copy.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. I thought putting `var contentView: ContentView?` in `JSHandler` like I originally did works since `ContentView?` could be `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Just make myWebView a `lazy` variable, This makes sure that the jsHandler is initialised before WebView.

```
lazy var myWebView: WKWebView = {
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let controller = WKUserContentController()
    controller.add(myJSHandler , name: "documentReady")
    config.userContentController = controller
    return WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
}()
```

Comment: This won't work for SwiftUI view, as it has not modifiable self.